# Removing dtype: float64 and 0 from the below data in my list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, arraylist

I have following data in my list [0   -3.728107
dtype: float64, 0   -2.459012
dtype: float64, 0   -2.926203
dtype: float64, 0   -1.766479
dtype: float64, 0   -2.33429
dtype: float64, 0   -2.743715
dtype: float64, 0   -2.458658
dtype: float64, 0   -1.901353
dtype: float64, 0   -3.511518
dtype: float64, 0   -2.386804
dtype: float64, 0   -3.782853
dtype: float64, 0   -2.915635
dtype: float64, 0   -2.864467

I want my list to show only numbers, sort of like [-3.728107,-2.459012,-2.743715,-3.921402,-n....]

Please let me know if this clarifies my question and issue and what would be the solution for to have my list only contain the numbers and drop the 0 with space and the text 'dtype: float64'?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please give a formatted input/output?

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a list:

```
[i for i in my_list if i != 0]
```

Or:

```
[i for i in my_list if i] # using the fact that 0 is evaluated as False
```